# Web.config redirect one domain to non-https folder and another domain to https folder

Tags: web-config, url-rewriting

I have a domain alias for my site. I would like to know how to redirect requests for domainA.ext to `https://domainA.ext/folderA` and requests for domainB.ext to `http://domainB.ext/folderB`

Presently I have the following rule to redirect all http requests to https but it redirects ALL requests to https:

```
<rule name="Redirect to https" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.mydomain.ext*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://mydomain.ext}" redirectType="Permanent" />*
                </rule>
```

It is Windows server 2008, but my cms is in PHP.

Comment: Can you define all the cases and expected results? For example, what if someone hits `http://domainB.ext`? Do they have to be redirected to `http://domainB.ext/folderB` or stay on `http://domainB.ext`?

Comment: `http://domainB.ext/folderB` will do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't think of something more simple than 4 different rules.

The 2 first ones for `domainA.ext`:

```
<rule name="Check path folderA" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^folderA" negate="true" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="domainA\.ext$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://domainA.ext/folderA/" />
</rule>
<rule name="Check SSL for domainA" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="domainA\.ext$" />
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
    </conditions>                         
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://domainA.ext/folderA/" />
</rule>
```

- 1st rule: if the path doesn't start with `folderA`, then it redirects to `https://domainA.ext/folderA/`
- 2nd rule: if HTTPS is off, it redirects to `https://domainA.ext/folderA/`

And the 2 next ones for  `domainB.ext`:

```
<rule name="Check path folderB" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^folderB" negate="true" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="domainB\.ext$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://domainB.ext/folderB/" />
</rule>
<rule name="Check no SSL for domainB" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="domainB\.ext$" />
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^ON$" />
    </conditions>                         
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://domainB.ext/folderB/" />
</rule>
```

- 1st rule: if the path doesn't start with `folderB`, then it redirects to `http://domainB.ext/folderB/`
- 2nd rule: if HTTPS is on, it redirects to `http://domainB.ext/folderB/`